# An analog to rnorm in python

Tags: python, r, function, distribution, normal-distribution

Good morning!

I am looking to create an analog of some code in R

Basically, I have a function that, among other things, takes a seed provided by the user (default is NULL), along with a specific distribution (default is rnorm), and outputs 9 random numbers, saved as a vector "e".  This is what it looked like in R...

```
function (...other variables..., seed=NULL, dist=rnorm)

...other code...

e <- dist(9,...)
```

Now I'm converting the function to Python, but I can't quite seem to find an analog that would work, where a user can replace the base seed and distribution.

Here's what i have so far...

```
def (...other variables..., seed=None, dist=?):

...other code...

e = dist(9)
```

Answer (score 10):

See `numpy.random.normal` function ([doc here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html?highlight=random))

For instance:

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.normal(0,1,9)
array([ 0.33593283, -0.18149502,  0.43148566,  1.46831794, -0.72244867,
       -1.40048855,  0.52366471,  0.34099135,  0.71654992])
```

Comment: i sometimes get lost with the new np updates.. or is it this one ?https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html?highlight=random